# What material can withstand riveting or the compression of self-tapping screws?

Tags: print-material

I'm making a flip sign of sorts. The backing of a sign of this type is normally affixed to sheet metal, or the supporting structure behind the sheet metal. My fear was the plastic would crack during the riveting process (it's been forever, maybe this is not a concern) or if self tappers were used and someone just kept their finger on the drill.

Holes for fasteners would be present. The fasteners aren't to grab onto the backing, just the sheet metal or metal supports. The head of the fastener would compress against the sign backing holding it in place.

Was going to use a Shore 95A TPU until I realized that was softer than I thought. I don't have the experience to know which material is best. :( I have a dual extruder... would it be best to have the hole area in one material and the rest of the backing in another? Possible to fuse in some sort of metal ring?

Was hoping for a greyish material... lighter side if possible for the sign backing. This is because normally this particular sign setup is all metal with a nice all metal finish for the backing. It is the closest match.

The printer that will print the backing can print "anything"... that said it should be somewhat economical. :) If ASA is acceptable this would be great for smoothing purposes and UV resistance. The backing would be 1mm thick... fastener areas could be beefed up if needed; 100% infill if that was done.

Once attached the backing more than likely would not be removed unless something happened to it.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you happen to find your answer? I am hoping to rivet a 3d printed tube over a steel tube, but am not sure which 3D filament, if any, would best handle the pressure of the rivet without cracking.